# Specify a model in R given coefficients and covariance matrices

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I'm trying to implement a predictive model from a publication [see here for reference](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5810027/pdf/12882_2017_Article_804.pdf)

The paper specifies predictive models that are derived from a previous clinical study and provides the coefficients and covariance matrices for each.

I'm fairly familiar with fitting a model to data in R - but I've never had to specify one.

Specifically, I am looking to create the model so that I can leverage predict() to generate predictive outcomes for a different set of patients while accounting of the model's variability.

For convenience I've provided the one of the two models and related coefficients and covariance matrices, both are of a similar form. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
 
# Model 1
# TKV model
#  
# delta_TKV = exp(intercept + a x age + b x Ln(TKV_t) + c x female + d x age x Ln(TKV_t)) - 500

# delta_TKV - the change in total kidney volume (TKV) over a period of time in years
# age       - age of patient in years
# Ln(TKV_t) - natural log of total kidney volume at time t
# female    - boolean value for gender
# age:Ln(TKV_t) - interaction term between age and Ln(TKV)
 
# Coefficients         Estimate      SE
#  intercept            0.7889     1.1313    
#  age                  0.1107     0.0287 
#  Ln(TKV)              0.8207     0.1556 
#  Female              -0.0486     0.0266
#  Age:Ln(TKV)         -0.0160     0.0039

# Covariance           intercept        age        Ln(TKV)        Female      Age:Ln(TKV)
#  intercept            1.279758     -0.031790    -0.175654      -0.001306      0.004362
#  age                 -0.031790      0.00823      0.004361      -0.000016     -0.000113
#  Ln(TKV)             -0.175651      0.004361     0.024207      -0.000155     -0.000601
#  Female              -0.001306     -0.000016     0.000155       0.000708      0.000002
#  Age:Ln(TKV)          0.004362     -0.000113    -0.000601       0.000002      0.000016
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't known wether you can generate a model to be used with `predict` with custom coefficients. But you can use `model.frame` or `model.matrix` to generate a design matrix based on your formula e.g.

```r
data = data.frame(delta_TKV = 1:3 , TKV_t = 3.5, female = c(T,F,T), age = 40:42 )

model = model.frame(log(delta_TKV + 500) ~ age + log(TKV_t) + female + age:log(TKV_t),
                     data)
model 
#>   (Intercept) age log(TKV_t) femaleTRUE age:log(TKV_t)
#> 1           1  40   1.252763          1       50.11052
#> 2           1  41   1.252763          0       51.36328
#> 3           1  42   1.252763          1       52.61604
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1 2 3 4
#> attr(,"contrasts")
#> attr(,"contrasts")$female
#> [1] "contr.treatment"

coefs = c(
  intercept =           0.7889 ,
  age        =          0.1107 ,
  `log(TKV)`    =       0.8207 ,
  female      =        -0.0486 ,
  `Age:log(TKV)` =     -0.0160
)

model %*% coefs
#>       [,1]
#> 1 5.394674
#> 2 5.533930
#> 3 5.575986
```

i transformed the formula to make it like `lm` spec, thus the response is the logarithm of y + 500 and you must obtain `y` doing the reverse, the same apply if you were to use `lm`

Comment: This is directionally helpful - but as I can tell, it doesn't allow any variability to be built in based on the SE of the coefficients. What I'm trying to solve for is using this information to model out patient-level data that captures the uncertainty of the model.